# Do-While loop is not looping as While is executed regardless of whether it is true or false

Tags: methods, do-while

```
   static double myconversion(string farenheitinput)
    {
        double temporary = 0;
        try
        {
            double farenheit = double.Parse(farenheitinput);
            temporary = farenheit;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write("\nWrong! you must write a number");
        }
        double celsius = (temporary - 32) * 5 / 9;
        return celsius;
    }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {

        double celsius = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("\nWrite your temperature in farenheit: ");
            string farenheitinput = (Console.ReadLine());
            celsius = myconversion(farenheitinput);
            if (celsius < 73)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThat temperature is too cold");
            }
            else if (celsius > 77)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThat temperature is too hot");
            }
        }

        while ((celsius >= 73) && (celsius <= 77));
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe temperature is perfect");
        }

        Console.Write("\nPress any key to close program...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I'm using a method to convert farenheit to celsius. 
Here's the code that I'm using for my loop and the method, when I debug it shows that double celsius = 87.7 if 190 farenheit is input by the user which is a false condition for while and the code should loop, however it doesn't and steps into the while code anyways and ends the loop. I have no idea what is causing it so I thought id come here to ask.

Comment: the step debugger in Visual Studio is a powerfully ally, why are you not using it?

Comment: I did and it just steps into it, thats how i was checking the value of celsius at that point in time

Comment: you need to tag with the appropriate language as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Loop Conditional Expressions:

The way loop conditionals work is they continue when they evaluate to `true`.

runs `0 or more times` while `true`

```
while (boolean expression|reference == true) { // do stuff }
```

runs `1 or more times` while `true`

```
do { // do stuff } while (boolean expression|reference == true);
```

In either case on the first `false` encountered the looping stops.

#### Solution

What you did:

```cs
do 
{ 
    // input stuff
}

while ((73 >= celsius) && (77 <= celsius));
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nTemperaturen är perfekt");
}
```

should be:

```cs
do
{
   // input stuff
} while (celsius < 73 || celsius > 77);

Console.WriteLine("\nTemperaturen är perfekt");
```

do you see the [difference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx)?

#### Better yet is to avoid the `do/while` construct completely.

```cs
while (celsius < 73 || celsius > 77)
{
   // input stuff
}

Console.WriteLine("\nTemperaturen är perfekt");
```

You might be tempted to replace `(celsius < 73 || celsius > 77)` with something like `(!(73 >= celsius && 77 <= celsius))` but do not do it.

Avoid negation logic if at all possible, even when you think the negative is more *readable*, trust me on this. That little `!` is really hard to see sometimes. And even when it is, it takes a human brain more effort to think about `!(true)` and even more effort to think about `!(false)`.

Comment: I want the loop to end if the value of celsius is between 73 and 77, i get what youre saying but i need it to loop if celsius is not within that range of values so that the user can input another value

Comment: read the logic, you do not see the difference apparently, it does not get anymore explicit and self documenting than this.

Comment: yes that cleared things up it seems to work now, Thank you very much !